# Android Simulator not run, become Hyper-V not available in Windows 10 Home

Tags: react-native, android-studio, hyper-v

I'm studying React Native.
Unfortunately Windows 10 Home is not Support Hyper-V. Since, i can't use Android Studio Simulator.
Is there any way to run Simulator.

Comment: You didn't mention that the installation of HAXM failed. Please provide full information to get a more accurate answer. The installation log in your `%appdata%\Local\Temp` should tell you what's going on. I have Intel-based Dell XP 17 (bought it year and a half ago) and Win10 Home that was shipped with it and I have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where you got your information that you can't use it.

Android Studio's emulator uses HAXM (**H**ardware **A**ccelerated **E**xecution **M**anager) on Intel CPUs, which in return is also used by Hyper-V.

[image]

Hyper-V is a very self-absorbed technology that doesn't play well with others (just like many other things Windows offers) and having it **ON** is actually what screws things up and you need a workaround in that situation.

I also have Win10 Home on one of my computers and tried running the emulator with a default Basic task project on a virtual Pixel 2 with Android 8.1 Oreo. It works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, mine was AMD Processor, for AMD HAXM no need, instead have to install Hypervision for AMD Processor in Sdk tool.
It worked.